# (JavaFX)(SceneBuilder) How can I automatically resize the scene when the window is resized if everything is set into a AnchorPane?

Tags: java, javafx, resize, fxml

All of my code in the fxml file is set inside an anchor pane and I was wondering if there was a simple way to allow the entire scene to auto-resize when the Window is resized?

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="csgocaseopener.InventoryController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@back.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="38.0" layoutY="65.0" prefHeight="270.0" prefWidth="525.0" />
      <ImageView fx:id="backbtn" fitHeight="45.0" fitWidth="45.0" layoutY="-1.0" onMouseClicked="#handleInventoryBack" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-1.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@backbtn.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: Your `AnchorPane` is resizing when you resize Window. In given code you fill the whole `Scene` with image, so I assume that you want to resize image to fill window.

Comment: Yea I just want everything to fill the size of the window

Answer (score 0):

Bind `ImaveView` fit to width/height property to `Stage` width/height property. This solution will not keep image ratio so it will be deformed.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.png")));
//imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);  //uncomment to keep image ratio.
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
```